# Python shows wx window,but menu bar is not displayed. Why?

Tags: python, wxwidgets, show, menubar

I've installed wxPython on my mac and tried this program

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.CreateStatusBar() # A Statusbar in the bottom of the window

        # Setting up the menu.
        filemenu= wx.Menu()

        # wx.ID_ABOUT and wx.ID_EXIT are standard IDs provided by wxWidgets.
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About"," Information about this program")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit"," Terminate the program")

        # Creating the menubar.
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File") # Adding the "filemenu" to the MenuBar
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Sample editor")
app.MainLoop()
```

I started python2.7 to run it, it prompts a window, but it doesn't show any menubar, out of my expectation.

Did I miss anything in my program, or I need any extra python/wx configurations?

Comment: works fine here (using phoenix on python 3.x). The size of the window is too small, though. But I get the "File" menu as expected.

Comment: You might want to set a default size, to make sure the menu bar is visible. Try `self.SetSize((800, 600))`

Comment: is Mac normally showing all menus on top toolbar instead of in program window ?

Comment: Furas is correct! Just converted to mac from windows, all sorts of confusions!